# How does this FFT smoother work in c++/openframeworks?

Tags: c++, audio, visual-c++, signal-processing, openframeworks

I'm doing some tutorials for OpenFrameworks (i'm kind of a noob when it comes to coding but have a bit of experience so far w/ tutorials and learning what's going on and stuff over the past few years) and a major part of the code involves grabbing the sound spectrum of an audio sample and throwing the values into an array to control a float value. But I can't seem to wrap my head around what's going on here.

This is the relevant code (it's a VJ shaper that rotates and changes the size of shapes according to input from the sound spectrum):

```
header:
float * fftSmooth;
int bands;

cpp setup:
fftSmooth = new float[8192];
for (int i = 0; i < 8192; i++) {
        fftSmooth[i] = 0;
    }
bands = 64;

cpp update:
float * value = ofSoundGetSpectrum(bands);
for (int i = 0; i < bands; i++) {
        fftSmooth[i] *= release; //"release" is a float
        if (fftSmooth[i] < value[i]) {
            fftSmooth[i] = value[i];
    }
}
```

if anyone could walk me through the steps of what's going on, that would be great. I understand (sort of) that in the setup, an array called "fftSmooth" is being created, with 8192 floats in it, then being filled with zeros in the for loop after which the int "bands" is being assigned a value of 64. Then in the update, another array called "value" is being created with 64 floats in it by looking at "bands", which is also the number of bands in ofSoundGetSpectrum, which is grabbing the frequency levels from a sound file as it plays. I've looked at the openframeworks reference page for the sound spectrum thing and didn't really get any more clues as to what it's doing in this context, and i have no idea what the for loops and if statements in the update section are doing either.

Not knowing what's going on really isn't going to impact whether i can actually use the code or not, but i feel like if i want to actually build on this code (grabbing different frequency ranges etc) i need to know what the for loops and if statements in the update are doing.

Comment: Is there a typo?  The `for (int i=0;i<0;i++)` will never execute, meaning the `fftSmooth` array is never initialized.

Comment: oops, yes that was a typo, should be i<8192

Answer (score 1):

> [ofSoundGetSpectrum(...)](https://openframeworks.cc/documentation/sound/ofSoundPlayer/#show_ofSoundGetSpectrum)
>
> Gets a frequency spectrum sample, taking all current sound players into account.
> Each band will be represented as a float between 0 and 1.

This appears to be taking an instantaneous FFT, and returning the "strength" of each of the frequency bands.

I assume the second half of the code is run in a loop.  The first time through, it is just going to copy the current band strength into `fftSmooth`.  In subsequent passes, the multiply by `release` is designed to reduce the value in `fftSmooth` by some percentage. Then any new band strength greater than the filtered one will overwrite the old value.

If you animate plots of `fftSmooth`, you should get an image like this (minus the color) :[image: Spectrum visualizer from https://github.com/dpayne/cli-visualizer]

Comment: thank you for this explanation, it actually does help my understanding quite a bit. I do have a book with a chapter on FFT that i haven't gone through yet, i should maybe take a look at that for more info on how that works so i can know exactly what ofSoundGetSpectrum is looking at